# Adding a cron job without crontab

Tags: linux, cron

Is it possible to add a cronjob without using the crontab command? (Or anything else except editing files directly.) Is there a file I need to edit?

Comment: Much likely this question belongs on superuser.com, or the http://unix.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: how does "anything else except editing files" and "is there a file i need to edit?" go together?

Comment: @TomášZato Oh right sorry, didn't think about that. Is there a way to move or should I just repost there?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can directly edit the following files:

```
/etc/crontab
/etc/cron.d/*
/etc/cron.{hourly,daily,weekly,monthly}/*
```

These are system-wide files. In these files you must specify a username before the command to be executed.

In contrast, per-user crontabs are stored here:
`/var/spool/cron/<username>`

Comment: Edit just to format your answer.

Comment: I'm a newbie here. Don't not get used to parser yet.

Comment: Note: the user crontab `/var/spool/cron/<username>` should not be edited without the crontab command. When opening the file with a text editor, it says `# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - edit the master and reinstall.`.